# Помогите, пожалуйста, с таблицей, с размером ячеек

Tags: html

[image: Таблица с очень странными ячейками]

Пожалуйста, помогите сверстать табличку. Проблемы с боковыми 1 и 3.

Comment: Приложите код таблицы, включая стили.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так это делается

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="300">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2">2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td rowspan="4">1</td><td rowspan="4">2</td><td rowspan="3">3</td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="5">1</td><td rowspan="5">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="4">1</td><td rowspan="4">2</td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```